# add an event on the button which is included in the datagridview columns

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I HAVE A WINDOWS APPLICATION. in this i have a form on which there is a datagridview.
now i am populating the datagridview with **EMPLOYEE MASTER** in the database. so when the datagrid is populated i also have 2 extra buttons as other 2 cloumns in the datagrid. those are **EDIT & DELETE** now so each row in the datagrid has these buttons. now i want to add proper edit and delete functionality on the click of these buttons. for edit a new form should open. having all the info abt tht particular employee.
please help

here is the code :

```
private void frmemployee_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            cmd.Connection = con;
            con.Open();
            adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            cmd.CommandText = "Select * from employee";
            adp.Fill(dsemployee,"employee");
            dataGridView1.DataSource = null;
            dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dsemployee.Tables[0];
            dataGridView1.Columns[0].Visible = false;
            DataGridViewButtonColumn editcolumn = new DataGridViewButtonColumn();
            editcolumn.UseColumnTextForButtonValue = true;
            editcolumn.Text = "EDIT";
            editcolumn.Name = "EDIT";
            editcolumn.DataPropertyName = "EDIT";
            editcolumn.HeaderText = "EDIT";
            dataGridView1.Columns.Add(editcolumn);

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would handle that in `DataGridView` `CellClick` event:

```
private void GridCellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.RowIndex < 0 || e.ColumnIndex < 0)
    {
        return;
    }

    if (dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "EDIT")
    {
        //edit logic here
    }
    else if (dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "DELETE")
    {
        //delete logic here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should subscribe to [DataGridView.CellContentClick](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellcontentclick.aspx)  event, as much as I'm aware of and handling that, figure out on what *concrete* cell click was done, so execute appropriate actions.

Answer (score 0):

Continuing with gzaxx'x answer, in the logic part, you could pass the primary key of the selected table row from your current form to the new form. assuming it is an integer in the first column, you can write something like this

> private void GridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
>
> {
>
> int prim_key = (int)dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value;
>
> // Open then the new form, you wish to edit in and pass the primary key
>
> Form2 f2 = new Form2(prim_key);
>
> f2.ShowDialog();
>
> }

Use a constructor in form2 to accept this value and you can populate your form from the db

> public Form2(int primkey) { }